# How recursion in scala case class(logical functions)

Tags: scala

when I studying programming and the task in scala I crashed the problem

the error code is class type required but Bool found
case class TrueBool extends Bool

I try many way but I can't matched type

```
    sealed trait Bool
case class True[Bool]() extends Bool
case class False[Bool]() extends Bool
case class And[Bool](elem1: Bool ,elem2: Bool) extends Bool
case class Or[Bool](elem1: Bool, elem2: Bool) extends Bool
case class Neg[Bool](elem1: Bool) extends Bool
case class Imply[Bool](elem1: Bool, elem2: Bool) extends Bool

def formula(fma: Bool): Boolean = fma match {
  // use recursion function and make consist of logical operation Neg, Or, And, Imply 
  case True() => true
  case False() => false
  case And(elem1, elem2) => if(formula(elem1) && formula(elem2)){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
  case Or(elem1, elem2) => if(formula(elem1) || formula(elem2)){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
  case Neg(elem1) => if( formula(elem1) ){
    return false
  }else{
    return true
  }
  case Imply(elem1, elem2) => if(formula(elem1)){
    if(formula(elem2)){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }else{
    return false
  }
}

println("** p10 **")
val fma = Imply(And(True, Or(True, False)), False)
println(formula(fma))
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> `case class True[Bool]() extends Bool`

I do not think this does what you want. You introduce a type parameter `Bool`, which is completely unrelated to your `Bool` trait.

You cannot extend a (generic) type parameter. This is the same as:

`case class True[B]() extends B`